# apt-get error 503

Tags: linux-mint, apt

I tried installing pyqt4-dev-tools on Linux Mint using:

```
sudo apt-get install pyqt4-dev-tools
```

After a few prompts the installation is aborted with the following message:

```
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main pyqt4-dev-tools i386 4.9.1-2ubuntu1
503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/p/python-qt4/pyqt4-dev-tools_4.9.1-2ubuntu1_i386.deb  503  Service Unavailable [IP: 91.189.91.15 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

I tried running `apt-get --fix-missing`, but ran into the same error, and running `apt-get update` doesn't help either.

How can I resolve this 503 error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

503 Service Unavailable means that the remote web site is down. Try again in a few minutes.